# Values won't show to labels when I change the ComboBox data value

Tags: vb6

I'm working on this payroll system for a company but somehow whenever I change the employee ID in the ComboBox it wont display the employee information on the labels.

I've tried changing the syntax of the query but still nothing

```
Dim cbo_id As New CAutoCompleteComboBox
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub cboEmpID_Change()

  On Error GoTo err:

  If Me.cboEmpID.Text = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

  If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close

  rs.Open "Select * from tblEmp where EM_ID = ' & cboEmpID.Text & '", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic

  Do While rs.EOF = True
    Me.lblName.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("NAME").Value
    Me.lblDept.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("DEPT").Value
    Me.lblPosition.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("POSITION").Value
    Me.lblRate.Caption = FormatNumber(CCur(rs.Fields("Basic_Rate").Value), 2)
    Me.lblStatus.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("Emp_Stat").Value
    Me.lblPerDay.Caption = FormatNumber(CCur(Me.lblRate.Caption / 30), 2)
    Me.lblNetPay.Caption = FormatNumber(CCur(Me.lblRate.Caption), 2)
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop

Exit Sub

err:
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I know nothing about recordsets, but the line `Do While rs.EOF = True` looks wrong. Maybe `Do Until`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think that you are only expecting one row of data back from your request, so just code an If to check that a row was returned.  I don't have VB6 any more but this code should do the job:

```
Private Sub cboEmpID_Change()
  On Error GoTo err:
  If Me.cboEmpID.Text = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

  If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close

  rs.Open "Select * from tblEmp where EM_ID = ' & cboEmpID.Text & '", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic

  If rs.EOF = False Then
        Me.lblName.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("NAME").Value
        Me.lblDept.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("DEPT").Value
        Me.lblPosition.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("POSITION").Value
        Me.lblRate.Caption = FormatNumber(CCur(rs.Fields("Basic_Rate").Value), 2)
        Me.lblStatus.Caption = " " & rs.Fields("Emp_Stat").Value
        Me.lblPerDay.Caption = FormatNumber(CCur(Me.lblRate.Caption / 30), 2)
        Me.lblNetPay.Caption = FormatNumber(CCur(Me.lblRate.Caption), 2)
  End If

Exit Sub

err:
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```